# Filter sharepoint list based on dropdown list and text search box

Tags: powerapps

on my canvas app I have the following elements:

- Sharepoint list called DataMarketTable- Columns are Plate, Maker, Model, Client
- Dropdown list called "Dropdown1" and element captured from a table in excel file called Table1.List with the possible filter cluster  - All, Maker, Model, Client
- TextInput1 that allows to identify a specific value for the element identified in dropdown.

I've tried with the All value in the DD list as follow

```
If(Dropdown1.Selected.List = "All"; 'DataMarketTable')
```

and it shows me correctly all the elements in the list.

If I try to filter based on Client and search box as follow

```
Search(If(Dropdown1.Selected.Status = "Client"; Filter('DataMarketTable'; Client = Dropdown1.Selected.Status)); TextInput1.Text; "Client")
```

it doesn't give me any error but if I type in the search button, I'm not receiving results

Help?

Comment: Hello, 

You filter your datasource where all rows witch the value "Client" is in the column Client, then you filter by searching a text in the same column Client.

Did your Filter formala retrieves results before trying to use the Search formula ?

Have a good day

Comment: Hi @Nackoo, the search formula structured "Search(TextInput1.Text; "Client")" works perfectly because I'm able to filter the list according to the text. About the filter part, I don't know if it works due to the absence of element used to filter the list. In my case I want to use both dropdown list and search box to filter the SP list

Comment: Hello @Lirico, what are the options in the Dropdown1 component ? When we translate the formula "If(Dropdown1.Selected.Status = "Client"; Filter('DataMarketTable'; Client = Dropdown1.Selected.Status))", we have "Rows where the Client column = "Client" ", you want to use your Dropdown to define the searching column it is that ?

Comment: Thrugh the dropdown list I want to select the column to be filtered with search box

Comment: I made some test and it's appear do not be possible and you need to put your search column directly, I suggest you to code this with some If conditions the values and the column you want to search like this : If(Dropdown1.Selected.Status = "Client"; Filter('DataMarketTable'; TextInput1.Text in Client) )